# VS Code - How to have Terminal pane open by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

In Visual Studio Code when I open the application I have to re-open the integrated terminal window every time.

Do you know the steps to have the CLI pane open as soon as the application loads by default without manually doing `ctrl-backtick` every time?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

1. Install an extension: [Auto Run
   Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabrielgrinberg.auto-run-command).
2. Reload Visual Studio Code after installation.
3. In settings <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd> add following:

```js
"auto-run-command.rules": [
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.new",
    },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new, so I can't post comments yet. But I think an improvement to the solution offered by @victor-s is to use `workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal`, since that won't create a new terminal if one is already open.

Answer (score 0):

No built in way to do this , however you can submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).
Or wait for [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Snowlie.terminalautoshow) extension to mature.

Comment: Thanks Jason, just added the feature request to VS Code's github.

Comment: @robhitt Could you please share the GitHub issue link?

Comment: @Manas - No problem, here you go - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43105